# activecell.formula with RC notation and vlookup not working vba

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, excel-r1c1-notation

I have this code and I cannot get it to work with RC notation

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[1],ARTICULOS!$A:$I,4,FALSE)"
```

The value that I'm looking for is 1 column after the "activecell".

Comment: You're mixing both [R1C1 and A1 notation](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/cell-references-a1-r1c1-notation.htm).  Why not stick with one or the other?  (preferably A1)

Comment: You cannot mis r1c1 notation and a1 notation.  Can get the second argument to C1:C9

Comment: because i need to generalize the formula, but the data is in other sheet. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Scott pointed out, you cannot mix **R1C1** and **A1** notation.

Whatever it is you're trying to do, there is probably a more efficient way to accomplish it, but for now, this should give roughly your desired result: a `VLOOKUP` formula with a `lookup_value` of whatever is in one cell to the right of the `ActiveCell`.

`ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1)),ARTICULOS!$A:$D,4,FALSE)"`

Note that I also changed the `lookup_range` to stop on column `D` because if you're looking in the 4th column starting with `A`, then `D` would be the last needed column.

Also note that I removed R1C1 since it's not needed here.

There's also probably a better method that using `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1))` but I can't think of it just now, and this way works too.

---

### More Information:

- Office Support : [**`INDIRECT` function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)
- Office Support : [**`ADDRESS` function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/article/address-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89)
- BetterSolutions : [**`A1` or `R1C1` Notation**](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/cell-references-a1-r1c1-notation.htm)
- Office Support : [**Create or change a cell reference**](https://support.office.com/article/create-or-change-a-cell-reference-c7b8b95d-c594-4488-947e-c835903cebaa)